# slack: how to launch outlook from slack app

Tags: outlook, slack, slack-api

how to launch outlook from slack app

I can launch outlook from web browser and below is react code

```
how to launch outlook from slack appconst Mailto = ({ email, subject, body, children }) => {
  return (
    <a href={`mailto:${email}?subject=${encodeURIComponent(subject) || ''}&body=${encodeURIComponent(body) || ''}`}>{children}</a>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Mailto email="foo@bar.baz" subject="Hello & Welcome" body="Hello world!">
    Mail me!
  </Mailto>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible out of the box, but you could try to add some plug-in to you slack, like "Clerk - Email for Slack"  (https://clerk.chat/email/)